# Совместимы ли 100 Gigabit Ethernet и Ethernet?

Tags: сеть, ethernet, совместимость

Совместимы ли они по формату кадров и могут ли образовывать составную сеть без необходимости транслирования кадров? Ничего конкретного не смог найти по этому поводу.

Comment: Ну в википедии про 100 gbit написано: "_При разработке PHY-части стандарта ставились цели:

сохранить формат кадров Ethernet стандарта 802.3, использующих формат 802.3 MAC;_"

Comment: Наш преподаватель считает, что нет, а информацию не найти по этому поводу

Comment: А что подразумевается под Ethernet? чистый 802.3? Судя по общей информации формат кадра сохранён на уровне MAC. В принципе можно поискать спецификацию 802.3b на 100GbE

Comment: @vnn198, до сих пор не ответил на этот вопрос, как найду ответ, если хотите отпишусь сюда. Надеюсь я близок к нему)

Comment: @helldrg В целос по спецификации сохранён формат кадра совместимый с 802.3 т.е. это всё семейство Ethernet, я не так хорошо разбираюсь в сетях на низком уровне, но единственное что приходит на ум из несовместимого это Jumbo Frames

Comment: @vnn198, да совместимы, просто нужны были пояснения, наконец то преподаватель принял ответ)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Форматы кадров для Ethernet, как правило, совместимы по всему семейству Ethernet, можно просто переключать кадр с 100 Гбит/с до 10 Мбит/с (возможно, придется сделать это в два этапа, хотя, коммутатор 100G может не поддерживать еще 10 Мбит/с). Любые функции уровня канала (L2) обычно совместимы с любым физическим уровнем (L1), определяющим среду и скорость. Аппаратное оборудование определяет, совместимы или нет эти технологии. Минимальный размер кадра у Ethernet 64 байта, а у 100 Gigabit Ethernet 512 байт.
В целом эти две технологии совместимы.