# Какие форматы кадров у Ethernet и 100 Gigabit Ethernet

Tags: сеть, ethernet

Добрый день, интересует вопрос какие форматы кадров у этих двух технологий

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Совместимы ли 100 Gigabit Ethernet и Ethernet?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/775570/%d0%a1%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bc%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d0%b8-100-gigabit-ethernet-%d0%b8-ethernet)

Comment: нет, здесь интересует какие форматы кадров используют данные технологии, а из этого можно будет сделать вывод совместимы или нет

Comment: как вариант я бы мог спросить у разработчиков этих технологий, но я не знаю где спрашивать

Comment: Я просто боюсь что тут нет специалистов знающие эту тему, раз на прошлый вопрос никто не отвечал. попробуйте на английском stackoverflow

Comment: Спасибо, так и сделаю. Не подскажете, а а кроме net, networking и ethernet какие теги еще поставить можно?

Comment: Подозреваю, что лучше спросить тут https://serverfault.com, сетевые вопросы чаще звучат, чем на стеке или суперюзере.